# How to add synchronized-charts in drilldown?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to have `synchronized-charts` in my drill-down but in the official link, it creates a new chart of three, but how to add it in drill down?

official example:https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

my demo where drill-down requires synced charts:

http://jsfiddle.net/gkumar77/w9ngp63u/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create an additional, initially hidden container with synchronized charts and toggle the visibility of both containers to simulate the drilldown:

```
        drilldown: function(e) {
            this.renderTo.style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('drilldownContainer').style.display = 'block';
            if (Highcharts.charts.length < 2) {
                createDrilldownChart();
            }
        }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vd6cn4ra/

Comment: Thanks a lot man. it's aweosme solution to my problem. But, there seems to be a small error of synced chart not showing data if clicked again. please check and help. http://jsfiddle.net/gkumar77/w9ngp63u/10/

Comment: Hi Gaurav Kumar, I do not see any errors in your example. In the example that I provided to you, everything works correctly.

Comment: no, i took your example and updated it. there please check. following is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/gkumar77/w9ngp63u/10/

Comment: @Gaurav Kumar, Yes because you modify the `fvc.data` object each time you click on a point and only for the first time you have only one `y` value.

Comment: oh, so is there a way to have new value for `y` every time i click. should i destroy the synced chart every time i click back ?

Comment: @Gaurav Kumar, Please refer to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6ems5z97/. First of all - you should put some functions from point `click` event, to the scope outside the chart, because they are called unnecessarily several times. Next, you create a new drilldown charts each time - you should use `update`.

Comment: Hi! was on leave. So, am still facing some issue, i updated the code as u said but my update is still not showing any response. folowing the link of code: http://jsfiddle.net/gkumar77/dxt5on1a/3/

Comment: Hi @Gaurav Kumar, in `updateDrillDownCharts` function you unnecessarily use `map` method, which causes the creation of a bad data structure: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1r9t52ga/